# Is it appropriate to use "I can be a little bit careless" when talking about work?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

suppose a department manager, he doesn't want to be the kind of person who focuses on details. So he says

> I suppose I can be a little bit **careless** sometimes.

I am afraid that the word **careless** is not appropriate to use when talking about work, since it usually a bad word.

Cambridge Dictionary gives this definition, which could be a proof.

> not taking or showing enough care and attention

Is my understanding right?

Comment: Have you looked up 'careless' in a dictionary?

Comment: Are you asking if 'I am careless' means the same as 'I don't focus on details'?

Comment: Some managers prefer to delegate the detail to employees but that in itself does not make them careless.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey "Are you asking if 'I am careless' means the same as 'I don't focus on details'?" Actually, I doubt that 'I am careless' could be used to express the meaning of 'I don't focus on details', but I am not pretty sure, so I posted the question:)

Comment: I wonder if you mean 'care-less' rather than 'careless' ? (*not caring as much* vs *not being very careful*)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the speaker who is "careless"is describing themself, regardless of where that person is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careless means "without care" - saying you deliberately do not take care at work would not reflect on you. Personally, I wouldn't employ somebody who described themselves as "careless".

In the world of business, there are certain recognised *management styles*, some more authoritarian than others. It sounds like you are trying to describe your management style.

Two recognised management styles are "*democratic*" - this is a manager who involves their staff in decisions; also "laissez-faire" (a French borrow-phrase) which refers to a casual, relaxed style of management. Some people like this style, others may think it is too casual (careless).

Another term to describe management which focuses too much on details is "micro-management". You could perhaps use this phrase to show the kind of manager you are *not*. Also, "high-level" management means primarily concerned with major issues rather than smaller details ("low-level")

So perhaps you might say (in context):

> I suppose I can be a little laissez-faire at times.

or

> I suppose I can be little high-level at times.

Comment: I would reserve 'careless' for culpable failure to attend to important details - wearing jeans is casual; leaving  a machine with the power on and electrocuting a maintenance guy is careless.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That's really a different definition of "casual" - wearing jeans is a deliberate choice and usually chosen for casual (not formal) occasions. A casual attitude is synonymous with being care-free, and an *overly*-casual attitude with carelessness.