# Is "hands-off" a safe word when talking about work?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I guess the answer to my another question ([Is it appropriate to use "I can be a little bit careless" when talking about work?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239077/109190)) gives clear explanation about 2 types of management styles.

This is a similar question (NOT the same).

One of my friends is preparing to apply a position of manager in a company. He would like to describe himself as a cool guy that is high-level at times and willing to involve team members in decisions.

I am aware that "careless" is not a safe word for this kind 
of scenarios as it may imply meaning of "not taking or showing enough care and attention".

How about "hands-off manager"? Would the following sentence implies he is the democratic cool guy clearly and does not survey something like "he does not care about anything that would not reflect on him"?

> I’m quite a hands-off manager.

Comment: You will find plenty of advice on the implications of **hands-off** if you google it: https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/hands-off          ..............    https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hands-off

Comment: This is going to depend on the company in question. Some places might welcome a more hands-off and laissez faire approach, whereas others will have a rigid structure and chain of command, If you want to emphasise that he gets team members involved I'd probably use words like approachable, keen to engage team members, open to suggestions and so on.

Comment: @Showsni  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because, after you have talked about your previous question, it boils down to asking the meaning of "hands-off" which could be answered by a dictionary.

Comment: @Astralbee I think this question per se is a question about nuanced usage. "So the dictionary definition is this, but I am not sure the word can be used is a formal situation."