# Micro-management style does not mean to be involved in every detail, right?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

An answer to my another question ([Is it appropriate to use "I can be a little bit careless" when talking about work?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/239077/109190)) explains the word "micro-management" in detail, which is a type of management styles.

> Another term to describe management which focuses too much on details is "micro-management". You could perhaps use this phrase to show the kind of manager you are not. Also, "high-level" management means primarily concerned with major issues rather than smaller details ("low-level")

I guess even if a guy is a micro-management style manager, it is impossible have him/her involved in every detail, is my understanding right?

Comment: Questions about given answers should really be posted as comments on the answer itself, not posted as a new question. This is the second time you've made a new question out of one of my answers. I have given an answer below, but I've also voted to close this question because it is not really about English grammar.

Comment: The three related questions I've seen so far might be a better fit for [workplace.se].

Comment: @CJDennis Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quoting my answer so I might as well answer.

> "In business management, [micromanagement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micromanagement) is a management style whereby a manager closely observes and/or controls and/or reminds the work of his/her subordinates or employees."

Merriam-Webster's Online Dictionary defines micromanagement as:

> "manage[ment] especially with excessive control or attention on details".

Dictionary.com defines micromanagement as

> "manage[ment] or control with excessive attention to minor details".

While the effects of micromanagement are often felt by persons being managed, the definitions clearly show that a micromanager may exercise exessive control on all aspects of work, not just on the output of employees.

Your question of "is it possible" for a manager to be involved in every aspect of a business is not really an English grammar question.

Comment: it's also subjective as it could depend on the business (fish 'n' chip shop owner vs massive conglomerate)